# 2 clientes en un Servidor en Java

Tags: java, servidor, socket

En la clase de sistemas distribuidos, estamos creando hilos y sockets, el próximo proyecto tiene el objetivo de tener un servidor, cuyo código está un poco más lejos y hay dos clientes que se conectarán a ese cliente.

No podemos hacer el proceso de los dos clientes al mismo tiempo, es solo el proceso, lo que se requiere del primer cliente para conectarse y, cuando se realiza el proceso, el otro cliente no puede continuar con el suyo.

¿Qué podemos cambiar, o agregar a nuestro código, es posible hacer las dos conexiones y el proceso?

Nos han comentado que el error esta en el código por que el hilo si funciona, pero aun así no estamos seguros.

**SERVIDOR**

```
public class Servidor {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ServerSocket ss;

    try 
    {
        ss = new ServerSocket(4444);
        Socket s1 = ss.accept();
        conexiones con;
        con = new conexiones(s1);
        Thread hilo=new Thread(con);
        hilo.start();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    }
}}

class conexiones extends Thread{ 
Socket cliente;
InputStream is;
OutputStream os1;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos1;

conexiones(Socket c)
{
    this.cliente = c;
}

public void run()
{
    int x,y,factorial=1;
    int resultado = 0,resultado2[]=new int[10];
    String a,b,c, tipo;


    try 
    {
       is = cliente.getInputStream();
       os1 = cliente.getOutputStream();
       dis = new DataInputStream(is);
       dos1 = new DataOutputStream(os1);


        do
        {
            System.out.println("Esperando el tipo de operacion...");
            tipo = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("La operacion seleccionada es :" + tipo);

            if(tipo.equals("1"))
            {

                a = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("El numero para sacar el factorial es "+a);

                x=Integer.parseInt(a);
                for (int i=x;i>0;i--) 
                {
                    factorial=factorial*i;
                }

                resultado=factorial;

                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
                dos1.writeUTF(Integer.toString(resultado));
            }
            else if(tipo.equals("2"))
            {
                a = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Se seleccionaron "+a+" Para el fibonacci");

                x=Integer.parseInt(a);
                int secu=1;
                int secu2=1;
                int fibo[]=new int[10];


                fibo[1]=1;
                for (int i=2;i<=x;i++) 
                {
                    fibo[i]=secu2;

                    secu2=secu+secu2;
                    secu=secu2-secu;
                }

                resultado2=fibo;

                System.out.println("El resultado es: " +Arrays.toString(fibo));
                dos1.writeUTF(Arrays.toString(resultado2));
            }
            else if(tipo.equals("3"))
            {
                a = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Se selecciono "+a+" como el numero minimo de la serie");

                b = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Se selecciono "+b+" como el numero maximo de la serie");

                x=Integer.parseInt(a);
                y=Integer.parseInt(b);

                int serie[]=new int [10];
                int j=0;

                for(int i=x;i<=y;i++)
                {
                    serie[j]=i;
                    j++;
                }

                resultado2=serie;

                System.out.println("El resultado es: " +Arrays.toString(serie));
                dos1.writeUTF(Arrays.toString(resultado2));
            }
            else if(tipo.equals("4"))
            {
                System.out.println("Salio");
                dos1.writeUTF("Salio");
            }
        }while(!tipo.contains("4"));

    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENTE**

```
public class Cliente2 extends Thread{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try {
        String cad1,cad2,cad3;
        String resultado = "";
        Socket sc1 = new Socket("127.0.1.1",4444);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( System.in );
        InputStream is = sc1.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
        OutputStream os1 = sc1.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos1 = new DataOutputStream(os1);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Que tipo de operacion quieres");
            System.out.println("1)Factorial 2)Fibonacci 3)Serie 4)Salir");

            cad3 = bf.readLine();
            dos1.writeUTF(cad3);

            if(cad3.contains("1"))
            {
                System.out.println("Dame un numero para el factorial: ");
                cad1 = bf.readLine();
                dos1.writeUTF(cad1);

                resultado = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
            }
            else if(cad3.contains("2"))
            {
                System.out.println("Cuantos dijitos de fibonacci quiere ver? ");
                cad1 = bf.readLine();
                dos1.writeUTF(cad1);

                resultado = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
            }
            else if(cad3.contains("3"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el numero minimo de la serie");
                cad1 = bf.readLine();
                dos1.writeUTF(cad1);

                System.out.println("Ingrese el numero maximo de la serie");
                cad2 = bf.readLine();
                dos1.writeUTF(cad2);

                resultado = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
            }
            else if(cad3.contains("4"))
            {
                resultado = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println(resultado);
            }

        }while(!cad3.contains("4"));
        sc1.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Cliente2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Favor de traducir tu pregunta, estás en SO en español pues de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow **en español**. Acá, utilizamos la lengua de cervantes, tanto para preguntas como para respuesta. Sugiero que edites tu pregunta para publicarla en español, de otra manera acabará siendo cerrada. Un saludo.

Comment: También te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, y ganar tu primera medalla. Un  saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No podemos hacer el proceso de los dos clientes al mismo tiempo, es
>   solo el proceso, lo que se requiere del primer cliente para conectarse
>   y, cuando se realiza el proceso, el otro cliente no puede continuar
>   con el suyo.

Esta parte de la pregunta no es muy clara pero como suelen trabajar las aplicaciones que implementan un server es la siguiente:

1) El server abre un loop que corre hasta que se detenga la aplicación.
2) En ese loop se blockea el Thread escuchando sobre un puerto determinado.
3) Cuando entra una conexión por ese puerto el Thread reasume la ejecución y delega el trabajo que haya que hacer en un Thread hijo.
4) Solo para dejarlo claro, el loop pega la vuelta, y el Thread principal vuelve a blockearse escuchando sobre el puerto (se vuelve al punto 2), mientras el Thread hijo se encarga de la tarea.

En el código de la pregunta falta el loop en el `Thread` principal.

```
public class Servidor {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ServerSocket ss;
        boolean fin = false;

        while(!fin){
          try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(4444);
            Socket s1 = ss.accept();
            conexiones con;
            con = new conexiones(s1);
            Thread hilo=new Thread(con);
            hilo.start();
          }catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
          }
        }
    }

}
```

*(Como está el loop es infinito y el proceso se corta con Ctrl+C, también puedes agregar un metodo para cambiar el flag fin a true y agregarle una operación de cierre al servidor para desbloquear el thread y cambiar el flag usando este nuevo método)*

Las operaciones que ocurren dentro de los threads hijos no parecen tener ningún recurso crítico (que necesite accederse por un Thread a la vez), por lo que varios clientes podrían conectarse en paralelo y resolver sus operaciones en paralelo.

Nota: Me parece que también hay alguna confusión entre `Thread` y `Runnable`. Si bien la clase `conexiones` extiende `Thread`, me parece que la intención real es que implemente `Runnable`, dado que en el uso de la clase, al envolver el objeto en otro `Thread` (`hilo`), indirectamente solo se está usando el método `run`. Y los nombres de clases en java se suelen escribir con la primera letra máyuscula:

```
class Conexiones implements Runnable{
```

Runnable es una interface que aporta el método run() a las clases que la implementan que viene a ser un punto de entrada para ejecutar un proceso y es independiente del Thread en que corre.

Por otro lado la clase `Thread` (que aparte implementa `Runnable`) sí representa un hilo o thread separado de ejecución.
El mismo en su contructor puede llevar un `Runnable` que determina el proceso a ejecutar.
Cuando se ejecuta el método `start()` del `Thread`, este llama al método `run` del `Runnable`, que es ejecutado dentro del nuevo thread.